# have python script send data to javascript using JSON to change web page

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am working on an interactive display with sensors on a raspberry pi. My display is showing a webpage. I am using a python script to interact with the sensors. I want it so that when a user walks by, a different web page is displayed in the web browser. I have already tried changing to a different web page doing it straight from the python script. Unfortunately, it does not work the way I want it to. JavaScript works just fine for changing to a different page. I am thinking it might be good to have my python script send a message to a javascript file to change the page using JSON. Does this sound like a practical solution? Thanks.

Comment: I think what you're describing can be done by using `AJAX`. Read up on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ajax/topics

Comment: Yes, you need to use AJAX techniques on the HTML side, then you need a server to handle the server side, which you would do with the simplehttpserver.

Comment: Thanks guys! In the meantime, lets see how many dislikes this question can get! (not trolling, just making fun of myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your html file as a string in python.  This string can be modified in response to sensor input.  Write it to a file on your system where the html is source file exists; rewrite each time the sensor inputs change.  Set up a timer in Javascript, e.g. `setTimeout()` to refresh the page often.

Comment: I kind of like that idea. Like every time I want the browser to change to a different page, I have python write to a text file. I have 3 tabs in the web page: calendar, ads, messenger. if I want to change to ads, I can have the python script write to that text file: "ads". The javascript file reads this text file once every second. When it reads "ads", it switches to the ads page. Good idea?

Comment: Give it a try.  This approach does not require any specialized libraries.